# Can you hide a specific row in the recyclerview?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, row, adapter

[image: xml layout file]

I want to hide the A-match in a specific row as it repeats in the item row.
What should I do onBindViewHolder?

The second image is the desired result of creating the desired image with Photoshop.

[image: The result that I want]

Comment: Did you try to use holder.itemView.visibility = View.GONE ??

Comment: If itemView is not visible, there is a gap in the middle.

So, if only the layout of the row was hidden, the desired result came out.

That was a very helpful answer.
Thank you. Yoron

Comment: Your images all look exactly the same to me (except one says B Match), so I'm not sure what you want exactly! But if you want to hide certain rows, you can remove them from your data set. The simplest way is to have an ``allItems`` list and a ``filteredItems`` list, and use ``filteredItems`` as your data set. When you want to show/hide rows, use ``allItems`` to create a new ``filteredItems`` with the hidden rows removed, and call ``notifyDataSetChanged``. That way your ``RecyclerView`` will only try to show the items you want. There are smarter/more efficient ways, but this is pretty simple!